# Line spacing for wrapped text in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to change the line spacing in wrapped geom_text layer.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(stringr)
txt = c('one two three', 'four five six', 'seven eight nine')
p = ggplot(data=NULL, aes(x=1:3, y=1:3, label = str_wrap(txt, width = 3))) + 
  geom_text() + expand_limits(x = c(0.5, 3.5), y = c(0.5, 3.5))
```

[image]

But `theme(text=element_text(lineheight = ...))` has no effect because `theme` only works for [non-data components of the plot](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1859), so I'm not clear how to achieve this. Suggestions?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Just use `lineheight`, e.g.:

```
ggplot(data = NULL, aes(x = 1:3, y = 1:3, 
                        label = str_wrap(txt, width = 3))) + 
  geom_text(lineheight = .5) + 
  expand_limits(x = c(0.5, 3.5), y = c(0.5, 3.5))
```

(s. `?geom_text`)

[image]

Comment: Well duh! There's a lesson to read the full doc page not just the function spec.